# Operands of '+' operation must either be both strings or both numbers. Consider using a template literal @typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands

Tags: typescript, tslint

I just using tslint but this block of code throws me a  error.

```
 const MemberNumber = 'MBR' + pinCode + sliceNumber
```

```
Operands of '+' operation must either be both strings or both numbers. Consider using a template literal  @typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands
```

I tired with template method again throwing the tslint error.

```
const MemberNumber = `MBR${pinCode}${sliceNumber}`
```

```
 Invalid type "any" of template literal expression  @typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expres
```

how to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show where `pinCode` and `sliceNumber` are defined?

Comment: pincode and sliceNumber  both are string.

Comment: I am not convinced - can you include the code where they're defined?

Comment: const pinCode =  "600028"
        const sliceNumber = "887277272"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like `pinCode` or `sliceNumber` is of type `number`, so converting it to a string should work:

```
const MemberNumber = `MBR${String(pinCode)}${String(sliceNumber)}`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You've saved me from hours of frustration. You're the man.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert pinCode and sliceNumber as string

const MemberNumber = `MBR${pinCode as string}${sliceNumber as string}`;

Answer (score 0):

Typescript does not cast numbers to string implicitly, so you should cast to string first and then you can make concatenation with string.
One or more of your parameters may be number.

This will fix your issue:

```
const MemberNumber = `MBR${String(pinCode)}${String(sliceNumber)}`
```

Comment: Sure wish I could understand why TF Angular 15 is making me cast a string to a String!?